# Regex &#039; how do i regex this....?

Tags: php, python, regex, expression

SOURCE:

```
</div><img class="preview" alt="Jenifa&#039;s Diary - Season 2 - Episode 12" title="Jenifa&#039;s Diary - Season 2 - Episode 12"         data-lg="video_list" data-src="http://s2.dmcdn.net/VvYD3/300x168-917.jpg" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=="    /><div data-spr=http://s1.dmcdn.net/VvYBj/320x-DKa.jpg class="psprite pmode8"></div><span class="wl_chkbx js-wl_chkbx js-tipsy js-tipsy-ballon " title="Add to watch later" ><span class="watch_later icon-time font-lg"></span><div class="clear"></div></span><div class="play"></div></a></div><div class="media-block mrg-top-sm"><h3 class="title mrg-btm-xs font-lg"><a href="/video/x43xnnc_jenifa-s-diary-season-2-episode-12_shortfilms" data-context="/user/HomeOfNollyWood/2" class="link" title="Jenifa&#039;s Diary - Season 2 - Episode 12">Jenifa&#039;s Diary - Season 2 - Episode 12</a></h3><div class="foreground2"> By             <a href="/HomeOfNollyWood" class="link-on-hvr " data-user-uri="/HomeOfNollyWood">HomeOfNollyWood</a></div></div></div><div class="sd_video_griditem media media-stacked col-4 js-item" data-owner="HomeOfNollyWood" data-annotated="1" data-user="O5zXs9m23IUzK3vRFuBUJQ" data-position="20"><div class="sd_video_preview media-img span-4" data-id="x43xnnd" data-playable="x43xnnd"><a class="id_x43xnnd preview_link js-track " href="/video/x43xnnd_jenifa-s-diary-season-2-episode-13_shortfilms" data-context="/user/HomeOfNollyWood/2"  data-xid="x43xnnd"><div class="badge badge--duration">
```

Right now I have this Expres...

```
class="preview" alt=".*?title="(.*?)".*?href="\/video\/(.*?)\_
```

How can I improve my Regex to include the ' normally or exclude the

```
&#039;
```

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Use DOMDocument and eventually DOMXPath to extract the informations you want. Regexes are not the tool to use with html. Then if you don't want entities in your results, PHP has a function to convert them. Using this way you will avoid a lot of errors and you will learn a lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of `(?:(alt|title|href)="([^"]+)")+` then using [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) on the result.

https://regex101.com/r/cG0vE7/1